# don't add wordpress post "meta_input" if it is empty

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this query to insert a new post:

```
    $new_post_args = array(
            'post_title'    => empty($esc_title = wp_filter_nohtml_kses(wp_trim_words($_POST['text'], 10))) ? 'No Title' : $esc_title,
            'post_content'  => esc_textarea($_POST['text']),
            'post_name'     => sanitize_title($_POST['text']),
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
            'post_category' => array($_POST['category']),
            'comment_status' => $_POST['comments']
          );

      $new_post_args['meta_input']['_thumbnail_id'] = $_POST['images'][0];
      if (count($_POST['images']) > 1) {
        unset($_POST['images'][0]);
        $new_post_args['meta_input']['gallery_images'] = implode(",", $_POST['images']);
        $new_post_args['meta_input']['slider_mode'] = 'horizontal';
        $new_post_args['meta_input']['slider_auto'] = 'on';
        $new_post_args['meta_input']['slider_pause'] = '3000';
        $new_post_args['tax_input'] = array('post_format' => 'gallery');
      } else {
        if ($_POST['do'] == 'update-post') {
          $new_post_args['meta_input']['gallery_images'] = '';
          $new_post_args['meta_input']['slider_mode'] = '';
          $new_post_args['meta_input']['slider_auto'] = '';
          $new_post_args['meta_input']['slider_pause'] = '';
          $new_post_args['tax_input'] = array('post_format' => 0);
        }
      }

  if ($_POST['do'] == 'update-post') {
    $new_post_args['ID'] = $_POST['id'];
    $new_post_id = wp_update_post($new_post_args);
  } elseif ($_POST['do'] == 'share-post') {
    $new_post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post_args);
  }
```

For posting action, only if the gallery images > 1 then the gallery meta args will be added, but on `update-post` action I need to delete the args, not to add them empty `''` , I don't want to `delete_post_meta` after the post is published, I'm looking for a way to hook all meta values of the post and do not add them if they are empty, if this is possible I appreciate sharing the code.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some more context for the question? I'm assuming you're using the $_POST variable since you're pushing the data to the function to add the WP post

Comment: Yes, I send the post data via AJAX using $_POST parameters.

Comment: Ok so the insert action is perfect I assume? If you're updating and the update has no meta values but the original post had values, you will have to delete the post meta, if you update to an empty value, there is still meta but just with empty values

Comment: Yes exactly, and I don't want those empty meta values to stay there if the update function has those values empty.

Comment: In that case I think you're going to have to delete the meta values when the updated values are blank. It's much cleaner

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing this from the start, if we can hook `wp_insert_post` to check for empty meta values and `unset` them before adding the post, that would be fantastic!

Comment: I think the problem is that your question is posed as how to not have meta-values when updating. So the question is, how do you expect to remove meta-values that exist when updating a post if the update has no meta-values if you don't delete them? Where would the `wp_insert_post` hook come into play? Have I got this question completely wrong?

Comment: I just thought I can add empty meta values, and somewhere in my functions file I can hook into `wp_insert_post` or `wp_update_post` like done here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/105734/94165 and intercept the function to unset the empty meta values before triggering the function. I am making it complicated, right?

Comment: The problem with that approach is you're forgetting that each meta-value is a separate record in the `wp_post_meta` table so "hooking into" that function wouldn't delete those records, at best it may empty the value for the `meta_key` it would be less efficient in the long term than deleting the meta values. This is merely my opinion though, perhaps someone else with more experience could confirm

Comment: Thank you for your time Dan. I appreciate it :)

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck with your project